# Using Dynamic Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

im trying return a matrix from my tables.
 My two tables look like this:

```
**Employe_Course_Instance**
PersonNumber Year Period CourseCode Hour
111          2015   3     a1         10
222          2016   4     a2         4
333          2018   2     a3         8
444          2015   1     a4         5

**Employe**
PersonNumber FirstName LastName Salary Type
    111          A        LA     100   teacher 
    222          B        LB     120   teacher 
    333          C        LC     150   teacher 
    444          D        LD     120   teacher
```

I need a table looks like this:
where CourseCode and period will be data in table like CourseCode/Period and can only contain 4 periods. Salary to be displayed in rows in CourseCode/Period.

```
FirstName LastName a1/3 a2/4 a3/2 a4/1 Hours
   A         LA    100                  10
   B         LB         120             4
   C         LC              150        8
   D         LD                   120   5
```

and this is how i try to do this->

```
declare @ColumnNames nvarchar(max) 
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = ''
set @ColumnNames = ''
select @ColumnNames = @ColumnNames + quotename (coursecode) + ','
from bemaning

set @ColumnNames = left (@ColumnNames, len (@ColumnNames) - 1)

print @ColumnNames

set @SQL = 
'select * from
(select 
employe.firsname, employe.lastname, 
Employe_Course_Instance.coursecode  + '' / '' + CAST(Employe_Course_Instance.period as varchar (50)) as CourseCode_Period,
Employe_Course_Instance.year, Employe_Course_Instance.hours
from
employe inner join Employe_Course_Instance on employe.personnumber = Employe_Course_Instance.personnumber) 


pivot(
    sum(hour)
    for CourseCode_Period in (' + @ColumnNames +')

) as pivot_table'

--print @SQL
execute sp_executesql @SQL
```

The error i get->

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'pivot'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `alias`

```
AS <alias for the source query>
```

after the `FROM` statement. Thus having

```
select * from
(select 
 employe.firsname, employe.lastname, 
 Employe_Course_Instance.coursecode  + '' / '' +  
 CAST(Employe_Course_Instance.period as varchar (50)) as CourseCode_Period,
 Employe_Course_Instance.year, Employe_Course_Instance.hours
 from
employe inner join Employe_Course_Instance on employe.personnumber =   
Employe_Course_Instance.personnumber) AS pvtTable

pivot(
```

[**PIVOT documentation**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I have done that, but now it gives another errors:

Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Operand data type nchar is invalid for sum operator.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'a3' was specified multiple times for 'pivot_table'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's because you are missing a `table alias` for your inline view. It should be like

```
on employe.personnumber = Employe_Course_Instance.personnumber) XXX  
                                                                ^... Here  
pivot(
sum(hour)
for CourseCode_Period in (' + @ColumnNames +')
.....
```

Comment: Thank you! I have done that, but now it gives another errors: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Operand data type nchar is invalid for sum operator. Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The column 'a3' was specified multiple times for 'pivot_table'.